# Radius of Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n(x-3)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm trying to figure out the following:
Say we know the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n(x-3)^n$ diverges for $x=8$ and converges at $x=1$, what would the bounds be of the radius of convergence $?\le R \le?$

I was thinking, well, since the center is at $x = 3$ and it still converges at $x=1$ we know for certain that $x=4$ still converges, but that $x=5$ could actually be an endpoint and thus not converge (since $x=1$ could be an endpoint that happens to converge). For some reason though, the answer to this question appears to be $1\le R \le5$ which I don't understand. How can we say from the above information that $5$ is definitely included in our radius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question seems to be incorrect. Rather, the radius of convergence cannot be less than $2,$ since it converges at $x=1,$ but cannot be greater than $5,$ since it diverges at $x=8.$ Hence, $2\le R\le 5.$ I suspect that the text simply has a typo.

Comment: I've made a typo, it actually diverges at $x = 8$
, corrected it. Sorry!!

Comment: I've edited accordingly. With that edit, it seems fairly clear what could have gone wrong.

Comment: Does the Radius of Convergence include endpoints that may (or may not) converge?

Comment: Yes, if I understand what you're asking correctly. Put another way, if $R$ is the radius of convergence of the series, then (1) for $|x-3|<R,$ it converges, (2) for $|x-3|>R,$ it diverges, and (3) for $|x-3|=R,$ it may or may not converge. Since it converges at $x=1,$ then $x=1$ cannot be outside the radius of convergence (but may be an endpoint), meaning that the radius of convergence cannot be less than $2.$ Similarly, $x=8$ cannot be inside the radius of convergence (but may be an endpoint). Does that clear it up?

Comment: It does, thanks.  So albeit knowing it diverges for R = 5 (center + 5 would be 8), we still write that 2 <= R <= 5 since that 5 is a potential endpoint right?

Comment: @JakeDrone That's exactly right.